# Как посчитать сумму в массиве php для price

Tags: php, массивы

Требуется посчитать сумму в массиве:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [price] => ) 
    [1] => Array ( [price] => 16502.87 UAH )
    [2] => Array ( [price] => 16590.69 UAH ) [3] => 
        Array ( [price] => 16590.69 UAH ) [4] => 
        Array ( [price] => 16595.92 UAH ) [5] => 
        Array ( [price] => 16696.93 UAH ) [6] => 
        Array ( [price] => 16733.50 UAH ) [7] => 
        Array ( [price] => 16834.96 UAH ) [8] => 
        Array ( [price] => 16992.25 UAH ) [9] => 
        Array ( [price] => 17077.12 UAH ) [10] => 
        Array ( [price] => 17077.12 UAH ) [11] => 
        Array ( [price] => 17272.91 UAH ) [12] => 
        Array ( [price] => 17272.91 UAH ) )
```

Comment: Откуда берется этот массив?

Comment: PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Comment: foreach($html->find('tr') as $article) {
    $item['price'] = $article->find('td.column-price', 0)->plaintext;
    $articles[] = $item;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sum = 0;

foreach ($array as $item) {
   $sum += (float) $item['price'];
}

echo $sum;
```

Comment: За что минус-то? Хоть пишите причину...

Comment: 016568.733159.3949750.086634683042.9399776.43116611.3133511.9150504.1167581.3184658.4201931.3219204.2 Такая цифра

Comment: Возможно у вас какие-то лишние данные попадают в массив?

Comment: echo $sum; отдаёт все операции.

Comment: 0
16568.7
33159.39
49750.08
66447.01
83180.51
100081.0
117073.2
134150.3
151227.4
168500.3
185773.2 это $sum = 0;
foreach ($articles as $item) {
   $sum += $item['price'];
   echo "</br>";
$sum = substr($sum, 0, 8);
echo $sum;

Comment: Потому что у вас оператор echo sum внутри массива.

Comment: Нет. foreach($html->find('tr') as $article) {
    $item['price'] = $article->find('td.column-price', 0)->plaintext;
    $articles[] = $item; 

}
$sum = 0;
foreach ($articles as $item) {
   $sum += $item['price'];
   echo "</br>";
echo $sum;
}

Comment: Ну вот же foreach ($articles as $item) { $sum += $item['price']; echo "</br>"; echo $sum; }

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное, протупил сегодня день! Всего!